# Android StackOverflow issue

Tags: android, android-activity, stack-overflow

i am using `ActivityGroup` in android application for the managing the tab in different activities, and also managing the internal navigation in the activity by

```
    Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BookNowSetDateTime.class);
        activity3Intent.putExtra("contextvalue", context_value);
        replaceContentView("activity3", activity3Intent);


    protected void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); this.setContentView(view);

    }
```

Now because this internal navigation by Intent my application getting error :

```
  02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344): MaidPro fatal error : null
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344): java.lang.StackOverflowError
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1604)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3210)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3028)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
        02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1530)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1266)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
    02-22 15:27:52.920: E/ACRA(4344):   at android
```

- So and i am not able to catch this issue of StackOverflow is there any one give me the better solution to solve this issue ?
- How to remove or clean the activity stack on so this activity deadlock can be solved?

Comment: why u r using replaceContentView.

Comment: I thought there was an issue with "StackOverflow". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is deprecated.You must use the new Fragment and FragmentManager APIs instead.

I would recommend you to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for the implementation of actionbar tabs in the new way. It already includes the official Android compatibility package for Android <3.0 and it is really simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BookNowSetDateTime.class);
activity3Intent.putExtra("contextvalue", context_value);
startActivity(activity3Intent);
```

Comment: i dont have any issue with this intent navigation, let me explain you..

once i navigate activity-a to activity-b now is i once again change the navigation and now i try to navigate activity-b to activity-a and if this will done multiple time then on 3rd of 2nd time my application get this stackoverflow issue..

its because of that activities are goes in deadlock thats why it give me this issues..

Comment: and i am using replaceContentView because i am extanding my class with ActivityGroup and i need set that tab host in next activity as well so for that if i use startactivity then that tabhost will not shows in next activity..